# Azure AD - Disable account selection on logout

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I'm using MSAL to authenticate the users in AAD. While logging user off, page redirects to Microsoft's AD page where it asks to pick an account to logout from.

[image]

This makes sense if multiple accounts are signed in, but if only single account session is active then it seems pointless to ask the user. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: any solution have you got

Comment: @skyshine unfortunately, no. I had to select it twice.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the `login_hint` parameter ? you can provide the currently signed-in user's UPN as its value

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the `login_hint` that's been suggested you may also try the `domain_hint` parameter. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc